# Can't de-activate Visual Studio Extensions. ReSharper deactivated itself

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper, visual-studio-extensions

Most of my Visual Studio Extensions can't be deactivated or activated any more. I've searched for a solution and tried 'Clear MEF Component Cache' but that didn't work.

Another suggestion was to uninstall the extension, restart VS, uninstall the extension again (somehow the extensions are supposed to still there) and restart VS again. The problem here is, that some of the deactivated extensions cant even be uninstalled, so even if that works for some, it won't work for all of them.

I tried to repair DevExpress with the installer but its still the same. It's not too bad with DevExpress though, because DevExpress seems to at least be activated and still works. But somehow ReSharper deactivated itself and now I can't use it any more. I can't uninstall it via the 'Extensions and Updates'-window either. And if I hover the cursor over the 'Activate'-button, it says 'This product can not be DEactivated', which is odd, because it IS deactivated.

Any suggestions on what could be causing this and/or how to fix it?

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3.

[image]

Comment: Please uninstall ReSharper via running ReSharper Ultimate installer. please select Remove for them and select Skip for others. https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545359-Uninstalling-ReSharper-Ultimate-tools-from-Visual-Studio. and check if it works.

Comment: Reinstalling Resharper worked for me too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items are greyed out because they are installed per-machine, rather than per-user. Which basically means they were installed by an installer, rather than through Visual Studio's extensions dialog. ReSharper is one such application - it installs via an installer, rather than using Visual Studio's VSIX mechanism. You can't uninstall it from the extensions dialog, but have to go through the Add/Remove Programs dialog in the computer's control panel.

As for ReSharper being deactivated - check in Tools → Options → ReSharper to see if ReSharper has been suspended. In which case, just active it again. If not, go to Add/Remove Programs and either repair the install, or uninstall/reinstall.

Comment: It seems like my PC somehow removed ReSharper itself. Im not entirely sure what I did wrong before but after "removing" and resintalling ReSharper via the installer, it worked again. The Installer showed me that Resharper was "removed" already but at the same time didnt "install" it but rather "repaired" it, as if it was already installed. A little confusing but it workes again, Thanks!